# How can I put an user control inside a document viewer?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, documentviewer

Is it possible put an user control inside a doument viewer? If possible, how will it be that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following..

**Edit**
Added a `Grid` which binds its `Width/Height` to the `FixedPage` `ActualWidth/ActualHeight` to achieve centering

```
<DocumentViewer>
    <FixedDocument>
        <PageContent>
            <FixedPage HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                <Grid Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FixedPage}},
                                      Path=ActualWidth}"
                      Height="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type FixedPage}},
                                       Path=ActualHeight}">
                    <local:MyUserControl HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Grid>
            </FixedPage>
        </PageContent>
    </FixedDocument>
</DocumentViewer>
```

Unfortunately the Visual Studio 2010 designer is broken here and you'll get a message saying "Property 'pages' does not support values of type 'PageContent`.
This is reported here: [WPF FixedDocument object doesn't allow PageContent children](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/293646/wpf-fixeddocument-object-doesnt-allow-pagecontent-children)

As a workaround you can load it in code behind

*Xaml*

```
<DocumentViewer>
    <FixedDocument Loaded="FixedDocument_Loaded"/>
</DocumentViewer>
```

*Code behind*

```
private void FixedDocument_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FixedDocument fixedDocument = sender as FixedDocument;

    MyUserControl myUserControl = new MyUserControl();
    myUserControl.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
    myUserControl.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;

    Grid grid = new Grid();            
    grid.Children.Add(myUserControl);

    FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
    fixedPage.Children.Add(grid);

    Binding widthBinding = new Binding("ActualWidth");
    widthBinding.Source = fixedPage;
    Binding heightBinding = new Binding("ActualHeight");
    heightBinding.Source = fixedPage;
    grid.SetBinding(Grid.WidthProperty, widthBinding);
    grid.SetBinding(Grid.HeightProperty, heightBinding);

    PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
    (pageContent as IAddChild).AddChild(fixedPage);

    fixedDocument.Pages.Add(pageContent);
}
```

Comment: one more question, how can I center the user control in the page? Because it appears in the corner

Comment: @oscar.fimbres: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted so other people can easier be helped by it :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Meleak! What a pity VS is broken for the fixed pages in design